# buttons in row, how to make it take 100% of space?

Tags: html, css

I got a buttons row in the following html:

HTML :

```
<div class="buttons">
     <div><input type="button"/></div>
     <div><input type="button"/></div>
     <div><input type="button"/></div>
     <div><input type="button"/></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.buttons > div
{
   float:left;
   margin-left:25px;
}
```

For some rows, the buttons, only 3 buttons will be visible, some will have only 2 buttons visible.

How do I make the visible buttons take up the entire space of the buttons row so that there is enough space between the buttons (the buttons itself shouldn't be resized except the margin left space)? Width of the buttons row is 600px.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your "row" a list:

```
<div class="buttons">
   <ul>
      <li><input type="button"/></li>
      <li><input type="button"/></li>
     <li><input type="button"/></li>
     <li><input type="button"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Yay, bullets. I think you're missing something here.

Comment: Tried it, it doesn't work. When there's only 3 buttons visible, they still don't have enough space between them. If I add in space using margin-left, when there is 4 buttons visible...it wraps to next line etc.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `width:100%;`?

Comment: That won't work because the container is already at 100% (600px).

Answer (score 0):

The only way would be to use particular classes for each type of row, and calculate the correct margin sizes for each instance. i.e. classes called `buttons_4`, `buttons_3`, etc. with rules setting the margin in `buttons_4 li` and `buttons_3 li` etc.

To remove your margin on the first or last item, use the CSS selector `buttons li:first-child` or `buttons li:last-child`.